# jquery cannot call .dialog('moveToTop') on filtered list of dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bunch of jquery-ui dialogs appended to body. Some of them have the display property set to block and some to hidden. I want to obtain a list of the dialogs with display:block, pick the last of them and bring it to the top of dialog stack. The code I am using is

```
 $('.ui-dialog').filter(function (index) {
                return $(this).css("display") == "block";
            }).dialog('moveToTop');
```

Unfortunately I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'moveToTop'
```

How is this possible? The dialog is already initialized. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the correct line is

`$('.ui-dialog:visible').last().find(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('moveToTop');`

So it can be done purely with selectors and no need for the filter function. More about the :visible selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_visible.asp)